# Ruby converting array of hashes to array of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a ruby array of hashes

```
arr1 = [:a => {:name=>"Bob",:age=>"10",:city=>"NY"},
        :b => {:name=>"Mike",:age=>"20",:city=>"FL"}]
```

What is the best way to convert this to

```
arr2 = [["Bob",10],["Mike",20]]
```

in ruby.

Comment: It is not an array of hashes. It is an array of a hash whose values are hashes.

Comment: is this *really* what you have? It is an array with just one element, which is a hash of hashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use map.

```
arr1.first.values.map{|h| [h[:name], h[:age].to_i]}
```

Comment: Ohps. You mean `to_i`. Thanks.

Comment: Haha yes, I could swear it was other way around in question.